# im using float left but the divs are not going to aside

Tags: html, css

i paste a code that i found to centralize the content of container, but now im trying to use float:left and right and the divs are not going to the side.
Link for codepen of this code: https://codepen.io/racr-1/pen/oNqoZVQ

```css
.container {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>content of h1</h1>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use floats when using flexbox as you do. What you need is `align-self` on child elements.

```css
.container {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>content of h1</h1>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i see, but there's some way to centrilize and use float ? has you some article or something to i search ?

Comment: You can remove flex-direction: column. Why do you have it there if you want these to be in a single row

Comment: i didnt know to centralize content, and then someone give me this code and i paste

Comment: You can read this [documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Or use Elliott's answer if you want to keep the flex-direction: column

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you. I just added a div around div 1 and 2 to prevent `flex-direction: column` from being applied.

```css
.container {

        width: 65%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .div1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
        float: left;
    }

    .div2 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>content of h1</h1>
        <div>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```